# How do I manage the meta tags 'title', 'description' and 'keywords'?

Tags: panels

I enabled the [**Panels**](https://drupal.org/project/panels) module and created a **panel page** for a page in my site.

How do I manage the metatags 'title', 'description' and 'keywords' for a page generated for this panel page?

Any module to do it?

I need it to do it dynamically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Nodewords](http://drupal.org/project/nodewords) module will help in this regard. This module will help to add meta tags on nodes and custom pages as well.

Comment: Ok, i'll try 'Nodewords'. Then 'Page Title' will not help??

Comment: I install Nodewords but I can't see where to set the metas in my Panel Pages. Help please.

Comment: How are you managing your panel. Are you creating panel nodes? If so then edit your node for meta tag fields.

Comment: No, I didn't create a **panel node**. I created a **panel page**. In this I added **view panes**. I need to add **meta tags** to this **panel page**.

Comment: After installing the nodewords module visit the path '/admin/content/nodewords/custom/add'. Here you will manually define the path (path of your page) against which you want to add meta tags.

Comment: But this way the meta tags will have a **hard code** value. Is there a way to have them **generated dynamically** based in some of the value fetched for the **panel page**?

Answer (score 3):

[Nodewords](http://drupal.org/project/nodewords) is for Drupal 6 only. For Drupal 7 use the [Metatag module](http://drupal.org/project/metatag).

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Drupal 6 and you use Nodewords, you must:

- use custom pages configuration by URL to apply to Views.
- use 'node template' page if you use Panels.

Good luck